# Не работает двунаправленный буфер обмена VirtualBox?

Tags: virtualbox

Стоит - Windows 7
Функция Drag'n'Drop - двунаправленный
Общий буфер обмена - двунаправленный
Но не работает общий буфер, подскажите как исправить

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Насколько я помню, в V.B. действительно есть проблема с буфером.

К сожалению, Вы не пишете, какая ос у вас реальная, а какая - виртуальная. Ну и версия V.B. не была бы лишней.

В моём случае была виртуальная машина с линуксом Ubuntu-18 на реальной машине с Win-10, с последним (6.14) V.B.

Мне удалось решить её следующим образом:

1) проверить, что в настройках виртуалки стоит нужная галочка. Драг-энд-дроп не активировал, мне это кажется ненужной роскошью.

2) следовал инструкции
[на форуме вирталбокса](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=97052)
(проблема, как выяснилось, известная)

В общем случаве проблема в драйверах, которые надо ставить на виртуалку.

В моём случае это решается следующими действиями в виртуалке с линуксом:

```
apt-get remove -y virtualbox-guest-x11
apt-get remove -y virtualbox-guest-dkms
apt-get remove -y virtualbox-guest-utils
reboot
wget https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/6.1.2/VBoxGuestAdditions_6.1.2.iso
mkdir /media/iso
mount VBoxGuestAdditions_6.1.2.iso /media/iso -o loop /media/iso/VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
yes
reboot
```

Answer (score 0):

Была такая проблема с Ubuntu на виртуалке.

1. Нажал "Подключить образ диска.."
2. К Ubuntu монтировался диск, в котором я выполнил sudo sh VBoxLinuxAdditins.run
3. Перезагрузил Ubuntu